# How can i set the current values of a form field say a profile updating form with current user details

Tags: flutter, controller

I have my from that updates the user profile. I would like that the initial user profile values to be populated in the form field as the initial values before the user can make a change.

**Here is a form field **

```
  final TextEditingController _firstNameController = TextEditingController();
  Widget _buildFirstNameInput() {
    return TextFormField(
      controller: _firstNameController,
      style: inputTextStyle,
      decoration: formInputDecoration.copyWith(
        labelText: 'First Name',
      ),
      validator: (String value) {
        print(value);
        if (value.isEmpty) {
          return 'First name is Required';
        }
        return null;
      },
      onChanged: (String value){
        setState(() {
          isEdited=true;
        });
      },

    );
  }
```

When the user navigators to this edit profile widget, the user profile instance is passed as an argument to the widget

```
class ProfilePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final User userProfile;
  ProfilePage({this.userProfile});

...some other code...
```

I have tried setting the initial values for the input field by using the the controller of the input field in  initstate like so

```
  void intitState(){
    super.initState();
    _firstNameController.text=widget.userProfile.name;

  }
```

But this did not seem to work. How can i achieve it?

Comment: After `Widget _buildFirstNameInput() {` set  ```_firstNameController.text=widget.userProfile.name;```

Comment: Wow it was that simple, thanks alot

Comment: You're welcome dude if it works I'll push as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the `TextEditingController.text` in your `initState()` is totally valid.

### Full source code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: ProfilePage(
        userName: 'Thierry',
      ),
    ),
  );
}

class ProfilePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String userName;
  ProfilePage({this.userName});

  @override
  _ProfilePageState createState() => _ProfilePageState();
}

class _ProfilePageState extends State<ProfilePage> {
  final TextEditingController _firstNameController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _firstNameController.text = widget.userName;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(child: _buildFirstNameInput()),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildFirstNameInput() {
    return TextFormField(
      controller: _firstNameController,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: 'First Name',
      ),
      validator: (String value) {
        print(value);
        if (value.isEmpty) {
          return 'First name is Required';
        }
        return null;
      },
      onChanged: (value) {},
    );
  }
}
```

---

## !!! The other answer is WRONG

If you set the `TextEditingController.text` at the beginning of your `_buildFirstNameInput()` it will reset the form field at every rebuild:

[image]

### Full source code for easy copy-paste:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: ProfilePage(
        userName: 'Thierry',
      ),
    ),
  );
}

class ProfilePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String userName;
  ProfilePage({this.userName});

  @override
  _ProfilePageState createState() => _ProfilePageState();
}

class _ProfilePageState extends State<ProfilePage> {
  final TextEditingController _firstNameController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
          child: Column(
        children: [
          _buildFirstNameInput(),
          const SizedBox(height: 48.0),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {});
            },
            child: Text('MESS AROUND WITH THE STATE'),
          ),
        ],
      )),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildFirstNameInput() {
    _firstNameController.text = widget.userName;
    return TextFormField(
      controller: _firstNameController,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: 'First Name',
      ),
      validator: (String value) {
        print(value);
        if (value.isEmpty) {
          return 'First name is Required';
        }
        return null;
      },
      onChanged: (value) {},
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: True, i did not even realise till i tried changing the value.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [Flutter Hooks](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_hooks). It will make your code leaner:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_hooks/flutter_hooks.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: ProfilePage(
        userName: 'Thierry',
      ),
    ),
  );
}

class ProfilePage extends HookWidget {
  final String userName;
  ProfilePage({this.userName});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _firstNameController = useTextEditingController(text: userName);
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: _FirstNameInput(controller: _firstNameController),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _FirstNameInput extends StatelessWidget {
  final TextEditingController controller;

  const _FirstNameInput({Key key, this.controller}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextFormField(
      controller: controller,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: 'First Name',
      ),
      validator: (String value) {
        print(value);
        if (value.isEmpty) {
          return 'First name is Required';
        }
        return null;
      },
      onChanged: (value) {},
    );
  }
}
```